# Copy an array with row as a variable

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, copy

I am new to Excel VBA programming, and I am using version 2010.

I am trying to copy the contents of the cells in the columns listed in the array, so I can paste them on another worksheet.

The columns will stay the same but I want the row to be wherever the active cell is. The code is linked to a button.

When I Dim the array with a cell integer this works like a charm. I am hoping that there is a way to make the array dynamic with the row number being based on the active cell.

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim myarray As Variant
x = ActiveCell.Row
myarray = Array("Ax", "Fx", "Ix", "Jx", "Kx", "Rx")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HANDOVER")
  Cells(x, myarrray).Select
  Selection.Copy
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass an array as the column argument to `Cells`. What you could do is a simple `Replace` operation on an address string like this:

```
Dim x                     As Long
Dim myarray               As Variant
x = ActiveCell.Row
myarray = "Ax,Fx,Ix,Jx,Kx,Rx"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HANDOVER").Range(Replace(myarray, "x", x)).Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you, I have a custom function (see below) to look through headers and get the respective column number to be reused later.

However, I did have to modify your code (I got rid of the `.Select` which is useless and ressource-greedy) to use my function, see the combination below :

```
Sub Test_Mabes()
Dim x As Integer, _
    myArray As Variant, _
    Ws As Worksheet, _
    ColNb() As Variant

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HANDOVER")
x = Ws.ActiveCell.Row

myArray = Array("Ax", "Fx", "Ix", "Jx", "Kx", "Rx")
ReDim ColNb(UBound(myArray))

For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    ColNb(i) = GetColumnNb(Ws, myArray(i))
Next i

Ws.Cells(x, ColNb).Copy

End Sub
```

And here is the function :

```
Public Function GetColumnNb(ByVal SheetName As Worksheet, ByVal HeaderName As String) As Integer
Dim ShA As Worksheet
Set ShA = SheetName

For j = 1 To ShA.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If LCase(ShA.Cells(1, j)) <> LCase(HeaderName) Then
    Else
        GetColumnNb = j
    End If
Next j

End Function
```

Comment: Looking at what the other answer said, I absolutetly didn't get what you were trying to do, but anyway that would work too if you replace Ax by the Header name and so on!

Comment: Thanks R3uk. I am learning a bunch just looking at the different responses.